# Removing Variable Names From Line Of Code (Psuedocode in JS)

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed, replace

I've written a script with some regex to do some meta programming. However, I'm finding out that I cannot use some newer regex features like negative lookbehind and I can't install Perl or other possible solutions to get access because of the limitations I have on that machine. So, I'm looking for a bash script to accomplish removing certain words from a string of text, which happens to be pulled from a C++ file.

Here's an example of text input that I'm getting, which looks like a C++ function signature:

```cpp
int test(int aaaa, Vector<int, bool*> bbbb, Bar**cccc, Foo, Transform&eeee)
```

I'd like to remove strings that would represent the names of the variables. In this example, that is: `aaaa`, `bbbb`, `cccc`, and `eeee`.

The output should appear like this, as if it were merely a forward declaration:

```cpp
int test(int, Vector<int, bool*>, Bar**, Foo, Transform&)
```

---

My solution is to do a few things, but I'm not sure if there's a better bash solution for what I'd like to do and I'm honestly not familiar enough to progress far enough without seemingly getting to a dead-end.

I wrote this script in JS to help accomplish what I'd like. I hope it helps!

```js
var text = 'int test(int aaaa, Vector<int, bool*> bbbb, Bar**cccc, Foo, Transform&eeee)'
var index = 0
var insideparentheses = false
var deleting = false
var readdatatype = false
var insidebrackets = 0
while(index < text.length) {
    if(text[index] == '(') {
        insideparentheses = true
        deleting = false
        readdatatype = false
        readletter = false
    }
    if(text[index] == ')') {
        insideparentheses = false
        deleting = false
        readdatatype = false
        readletter = false
    }
    if(text[index] == '<') {
        insidebrackets++
    }
    if(text[index] == '>') {
        insidebrackets--
        readletter = true
    }
    if(insideparentheses && insidebrackets == 0) {
        if(text[index].match(/[a-zA-Z]/gi) != null) {
            readletter = true
        }
        if(text[index] == '*') {
            readdatatype = true
        }
        if(text[index] == '&') {
            readdatatype = true
        }
        if(text[index] == ' ') {
            if(readletter) {
                readdatatype = true
            } else {
                readdatatype = false
            }
        }
        if(text[index] == ',') {
            deleting = false
            readdatatype = false
            readletter = false
        }
        if(text[index].match(/[_ a-zA-Z]/gi) != null) {
            if(readdatatype) {
                deleting = true
            } else {
                deleting = false
            }
        }
        if(deleting) {
            text = text.substring(0, index) + text.substring(index + 1)
        } else {
            index++
            continue
        }
    } else {
        index++
        continue
    }
}
console.log(text)
```

EDIT: The variables can be named anything valid in C++, which would be `[_a-zA-Z]+`, not just 4 of the same letter, repeated 4 times... :P

Comment: I'm sure this could be done in `sed`, but I'm also sure it would be rather horrible. Would an Awk solution be acceptable?

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty decent with regex and `sed` wasn't working for the solution I had because regex features like lookbehind isn't available on my platform. If you come up with a `sed` solution that doesn't use lookbehind/lookahead, I could try it out! Also, `awk` cannot be installed, which is something I've definitely already tried. :P

Comment: What about Perl?

Comment: @tripleee, in the question, I specify that I cannot install Perl in the environment as a solution to this problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that. You can probably do some logic to divide the whole line into hold space and pattern space, then process the pattern space, then merge things back together; but these solutions tend to be write-only, especially if you are not very familiar with `sed` concepts. See e.g. some of [potong's answers](/search?q=user%3A967492+%5Bsed%5D+is%3Aanswer&searchOn=3) for demonstrations of what such solutions tend to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing these things using regular expressions rather than a specialized tool is
going to be brittle as it could fail on extra whitespace, for example.

Nevertheless, here's a `sed` version using POSIX
[ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) regexps,
assuming valid and simple input.
If your `sed` doesn't understand `\n` (GNU `sed` does) try
replacing it with a backslash-newline pair.

```
sed -E -e '
:S
s/^(([^<]*<[^>]*>)*[^<]*), */\1\n/
tS
s/(\n|\()([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)(\n|\)$)/\1\2 ident\3/g
s/([[:print:]])([ ]*[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)(\n|\)$)/\1\3/g
s/[ ]*\n/, /g
' -- data
```

where:

- 1st `s`: replaces the last (`*` is greedy) comma outside `< >` with
  a newline
- `t`: loops back if a substitution was made, to make one parameter per line
- 2nd `s`: if no identifier is present in parameter inserts one to simplify following substitution (3rd `s`)
- 3rd `s`: strips the identifier; the "print" [LC_CTYPE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) is defined as "alnum", "punct", and space
- 4th `s`: joins all lines to one

Test data:

```
int test(int aaaa, Vector<int, bool*> bbbb, Bar**cccc, Foo, Transform&eeee)
long tst2(Vector<bool*, str*> vbs, int i, Quux<Foo, int*>, Bar*bp)
longlong tst3(long l, Foo f, Vector<int, bool*, str*> vibs, Vector<int>vi, Bar**bpp, Phoo&)
int (*ff(int))(int*, int)
int (*pfc)(const char* p1, const char* p2)
```

Output:

```
int test(int, Vector<int, bool*>, Bar**, Foo, Transform&)
long tst2(Vector<bool*, str*>, int, Quux<Foo, int*>, Bar*)
longlong tst3(long, Foo, Vector<int, bool*, str*>, Vector<int>, Bar**, Phoo&)
int (*ff(int))(int*, int)
int (*pfc)(const char*, const char*)
```

Comment: WOW! This worked, even though it didn't directly answer the part of the question about converting the JS code! Thank you!! So excited!!

Comment: @crait: Well, your posting included a `sed` tag which I responded to. If you prefer another tool maybe the ideas in my regexps could be useful.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ \?\([abcde]\)\1\1\1//g' file
```

Delete globally throughout the file an optional space followed by either `aaaa`, `bbbb`, `cccc`, `dddd` or `eeee`.

---

EDIT:

```
sed -E 's/\((.*)\)/(\n\1\n)/;T;h;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;y/,/\n/
        s#.*#echo "&"|sed -E "s/^ +//;s/( |(\\*\\*|\\\&))\\S+$/\\2/"#e
        s/\n/, /g;H;g;s/\n.*\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' file
```

Split the line into three parts.

Run a separate sed invocation on the middle section.

Put the parts back together.

This will probably not cater for all possibilities (the OP will need to ameliorate the above solution) but should be a start.

N.B. It would be best to utilise the introspection of the original language to solve such a problem.

Comment: This is not the answer. The variables names being `aaaaa`, `bbbbb`, etc, are examples, and I thought my question made that pretty clear. The variables can be named anything alphanumeric, as they could in C++. This would also fail in the event that a datatype uses that pattern, as in `void whatever(aaaaa foo, int bar)`.